# sendmail replace html tag [LONG lines in email messages]

Tags: html, sendmail

I used sendmail to send below email to receipt. Strangely, One of the html tag  was replaced by  once I received it. Thus, the table looks ridiculous.

Does anyone have any clue what's going on?

Command used:

```
sendmail -t -f "test_mail@${HOSTNAME}" < /tmp/test_mail
```

Update:
By appending a newline to the end of each html tag solved the problem, but why??

Content of /tmp/test_mail

```
to: xxx.xxx@outlook.com
subject: CRITICAL: xhhmy92856 (xhhmy92856)
mime-version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<style>
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: calibri;
}
th {
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
  border-color: white;
  font-family: calibri;
  color: white;
}
p { font-family: calibri; }
</style>
<p>Environment statistics results, Date Fri Oct 12 13:10:22 AEDT 2018:</p>
<p>The following <b><font color=red>CRITICAL</font></b> issues were found on the environment statistics results:</p>
<table>
<tr><th>Group</th><th>Critical Status</th></tr>
<tr><td> (DB_5M_tables_row_count_check)</td><td>Library <b></b><br>Table <b>CIS_IPNE_CPU_5M</b><br>Less <b>IP_NEs</b> reported for some states in the last hour: <table><tr><th>Date Time</th><th>State</th><th>Previous</th><th>Current</th><th>Missing NEs</th></tr><tr><td>20181012.0745</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0750</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0755</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0800</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0805</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0810</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0815</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0820</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0825</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0830</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0835</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0840</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr></table><br><b>Action:</b>TEOCO, please check the GD Access Logs for further information. Identify first the NE, then the GD and just then look for timeouts or errors. (This check will be automatic soon)</b></td></tr>
</table>
<br><p>All checks are done.</p>
```

Content received:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><style>
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: calibri;
}
th {
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
  border-color: white;
  font-family: calibri;
  color: white;
}
p { font-family: calibri; }
</style>
<p>Environment statistics results, Date Fri Oct 12 13:10:22 AEDT 2018:</p>
<p>The following <b><font color="red">CRITICAL</font></b> issues were found on the environment statistics results:</p>
<table>
<tr><th>Group</th><th>Critical Status</th></tr>
<tr><td> (DB_5M_tables_row_count_check)</td><td>Library <b></b><br>Table <b>CIS_IPNE_CPU_5M</b><br>Less <b>IP_NEs</b> reported for some states in the last hour: <table><tr><th>Date Time</th><th>State</th><th>Previous</th><th>Current</th><th>Missing NEs</th></tr><tr><td>20181012.0745</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0750</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0755</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td>
 <td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0800</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0805</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.
 0810</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0815</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0820</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></ta></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0825</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0830</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0835</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3
 </td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>20181012.0840</td><td>NT</td><td>10</td><td>8</td><td><table><tr><th>NE</th><th>Access ID</th><th>GD Name</th><th>Error Text</th></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0001</td><td>1214</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMNAD_19_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr><tr><td>RENUIC0002</td><td>1249</td><td>GD_SNMP_COMMAND_13_MED3</td><td>TimeOut.</td></tr></table></td></tr></table><br><b>Action:</b>TEOCO, please check the GD Access Logs for further information. Identify first the NE, then the GD and just then look for timeouts or errors. (This check will be automatic soon)</b></td></tr>
</table>
<br><p>All checks are done.</p>
```

**Update:**
By appending a newline to the end of each html tag solved the problem, but why???????

```
sed 's/table>/table>\n/g; s/tr>/tr>\n/g; s#</td>#</td>\n#g; s#</th># </th>\n#g' /tmp/test_mail
```

Comment: the last closing `</b>` has no open tag that I can see. Not sure if this helps, but try fixing that and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks rlemon, i fixed last </b>, however problem are still there.

Comment: Make valid, well-formed html, then it will Work., incl. html, head and body tags.

Answer (score 1):

## LONG lines in email messages (SMTP RFC821/RFC5321)

### Diagnose:

Sendmail (by sendmail.org) breaks long lines in email messages. Other MTA/SMTP servers may behave similarly.  Sendmail limit is 990 bytes per line.

In your case the longest 4560 bytes line has been broken into 991, 991, 1977, 604 bytes lines.

### Recommended fixes:

Do not use **long** lines in your html template
**OR**
Pass generated html via `tidy` (html formatter program)
**OR**
encode messages body as quoted-printable (it takes care of too long lines)
It would require some extra headers
Quoted-printable encoding is also handy for **almost** ASCII charsets (usually ASCII/american-english plus a few extra/special letters)

### [RFC5321 4.5.3.1.6 Text Line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1.6)

> 4.5.3.1.6.  Text Line
>
> The maximum total length of a text line including the `<CRLF>` is 1000
> octets (not counting the leading dot duplicated for transparency).
> This number may be increased by the use of SMTP Service Extensions.

Comment: Thanks AnFi, however even the lines has been broken, but why only one of the </table> was replaced with </ta>, not others.  Server setting?

Comment: I may offer only too wild guesses.  Posting `Received:` headers may help **a little**.  It should show which types of MTA/SMTP+LMTP/IMAP/POP servers handled message.